Modern x86-64 architecture diagram?
I’m currently exploring the x86-64 architecture and have downloaded both Intel's SDM (5000 pages) and AMD's Programmer's Manual. To my surprise, I haven’t come across any high-level overview diagrams that depict the internals of a CPU core.
I come from an embedded MCU background (familiar with platforms like ADI Sharc, TI C2000, MSP, STM32, etc.), where detailed diagrams of microcontroller internals are much more accessible.
Without this kind of reference for x86-64 CPUs, I started working on my own diagram to map out a modern CPU core's architecture. However, I’m still in the early stages, and I’m sure I’ve missed several key components or concepts, as CPU architecture is not my area of expertise.
Here is the current version of my diagram (see image below):

I’d greatly appreciate feedback, suggestions for improvement, or, ideally, if anyone can point me toward existing diagrams or resources that provide a clear view of what’s inside a modern x86-64 CPU core.
EDIT
Here an evolution of my first version:


Different microarchitectures can implement the same ISA differently.  e.g. AMD Zen has split schedulers for FP/SIMD vs. integer.  Intel uses a mostly-unified scheduler with SIMD/FP execution units sharing the same execution ports as integer ALUs.  https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/ / https://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/ vs. https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen_2 and https://chipsandcheese.com/2022/11/05/amds-zen-4-part-1-frontend-and-execution-engine/

Agner Fog's microarch guide (https://agner.org/optimize/) is also very good: not diagrams but description in words of how the pipeline works and what bottlenecks exist, and what effect those can have on certain asm instructions.  For experimental measurements of latency and ports, see https://uops.info/ - it's machine-generated from microbenchmarks you can look at, and measures latency from different inputs separately so it's more reliable (no typos) than Agner's instruction tables and more detailed.

It appears that L1 Instruction Cache and L1 Data Cache are labelled in French, while the rest of the diagram is in English.

@EmilJeřábek You got me, the original diagram was in french. I translated only part of it in english. My mistake

FXSAVE area makes no sense as part of the CPU.  FXSAVE / XSAVE are microcoded instructions that store a bunch of registers to memory.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xsaveopt / https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xrstor . There's no special storage for it inside the CPU.  Also, I don't know of any x86 microarch with separate execution units for "FP" separate from "SIMD".  Intel does have a separate physical register file for x87 registers separate from XMM/YMM, which Skylake repurposes to also rename AVX-512 mask registers, but execution units for fmul are on the same ports as mulps.

Also your second diagram has a micro-op cache and an "op-cache"?  What's that supposed to be?  Also, for the record, modern uarches have queues between most of the blocks like fetch and decode, to better absorb bubbles.  Early P6 didn't, making it harder to tune for good fetch and pre-decode and decode throughput, since a low-throughput cycle in any of those stages would leave a bubble in the pipeline.  But omitting those simplifies the diagram.  The diagram in https://chipsandcheese.com/2022/11/05/amds-zen-4-part-1-frontend-and-execution-engine/ shows queues as separate blocks.

There are better microarchitecture diagrams around if you search in the right places. But rather than go through in detail, there's one broad thing I'd like to mention, and that's how registers are managed.
Modern out-of-order superscalar CPUs don't have a traditional register file. Maybe the control registers or model-specific registers are, but the architectural registers typically are not.
Rather, the registers that a programmer sees are indexes into a larger bank of locations. This is what register renaming does.
So in your diagram, you have "registers" under the schedulers, but you also have "registers" on the left-hand side. Those "registers" on the left-hand side don't exist.
Having said that, there is one place where there is kind of a traditional register file, and that's in the retirement unit. The reorder buffer ensures that instructions are retired in the order that the programmer intended, so as they are retired, this is updated to reflect the state of the CPU registers as the programmer understands them.
Take a look at this diagram of the Intel Core 2 microarchitecture, to see what I mean.

Another key point is that the functional units work on a modern version of Tomasulo's algorithm. The "internal results bus" in this diagram is what Tomasulo called the "common data bus".
In Tomasulo's original paper, each functional unit had its own reservation stations. In modern CPUs, functional units are duplicated (e.g. there are multiple integer ALUs) for parallelism, so it makes more sense to combine the reservation stations for all instructions/uops.

Core 2 is different from Sandybridge and later. P6-family does have a Retirement Register File that just holds the architectural state like you mentioned.  But there's no physical register file: in-flight values held in the ROB (Reorder Buffer) itself.  Most other OoO-exec uarches (P4, AMD, and later Intel) don't have an RRF, just a PRF.  The retirement state is just tracked by the RAT (register allocation table) having pointers to PRF entries, so retirement doesn't copy registers anywhere.

So in uarches that have a PRF (physical register file), some of its capacity is used up holding "cold" registers that haven't been written recently.  See https://web.archive.org/web/20240921204635/https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/05/measuring-rob-capacity/ re: measuring out-of-order exec limits from ROB size, or from PRF size if most of the instructions wrote the same type of register, so we can compare published PRF capacity with measured and estimate how many entries are used up on architectural state plus state of any private microcode-use-only registers that still get renamed.
